# set diffusion, specular lightening of square opengl 2.0 in Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am new to opengl ES 2.0. I want to set differents colors to each vertex of a triangle

```
   /*
     * Copyright (C) 2011 The Android Open Source Project
     *
     * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     * You may obtain a copy of the License at
     *
     *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
     *
     * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     * limitations under the License.
     */
    package com.example.android.opengl;

    import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
    import java.nio.ByteOrder;
    import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
    import java.nio.ShortBuffer;

    import android.opengl.GLES20;

    /**
     * A two-dimensional square for use as a drawn object in OpenGL ES 2.0.
     */
    public class Square {
        private final String vertexShaderCode =
                // This matrix member variable provides a hook to manipulate
                // the coordinates of the objects that use this vertex shader
                "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
                "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
                "void main() {" +
                // The matrix must be included as a modifier of gl_Position.
                // Note that the uMVPMatrix factor *must be first* in order
                // for the matrix multiplication product to be correct.
                "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
                "}";

        private final String fragmentShaderCode =
                "precision mediump float;" +
                "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
                "void main() {" +
                "  gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
                "}";

        private final FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
        private final ShortBuffer drawListBuffer;
        private final int mProgram;
        private int mPositionHandle;
        private int mColorHandle;
        private int mMVPMatrixHandle;

        // number of coordinates per vertex in this array
        static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
        static float squareCoords[] = {
                -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   // top left
                -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   // bottom left
                 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   // bottom right
                 0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f }; // top right

        private final short drawOrder[] = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 }; // order to draw vertices

        private final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4; // 4 bytes per vertex

        float color[] = { 0.2f, 0.709803922f, 0.898039216f, 1.0f,
                1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };

        /**
         * Sets up the drawing object data for use in an OpenGL ES context.
         */
        public Square() {
            // initialize vertex byte buffer for shape coordinates
            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
            // (# of coordinate values * 4 bytes per float)
                    squareCoords.length * 4);
            bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
            vertexBuffer.put(squareCoords);
            vertexBuffer.position(0);

            // initialize byte buffer for the draw list
            ByteBuffer dlb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
                    // (# of coordinate values * 2 bytes per short)
                    drawOrder.length * 2);
            dlb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            drawListBuffer = dlb.asShortBuffer();
            drawListBuffer.put(drawOrder);
            drawListBuffer.position(0);

            // prepare shaders and OpenGL program
            int vertexShader = MyGLRenderer.loadShader(
                    GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER,
                    vertexShaderCode);
            int fragmentShader = MyGLRenderer.loadShader(
                    GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,
                    fragmentShaderCode);

            mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();             // create empty OpenGL Program
            GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);   // add the vertex shader to program
            GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader); // add the fragment shader to program
            GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);                  // create OpenGL program executables
        }

        /**
         * Encapsulates the OpenGL ES instructions for drawing this shape.
         *
         * @param mvpMatrix - The Model View Project matrix in which to draw
         * this shape.
         */
        public void draw(float[] mvpMatrix) {
            // Add program to OpenGL environment
            GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

            // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
            mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");

            // Enable a handle to the triangle vertices
            GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

            // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
            GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(
                    mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
                    GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                    vertexStride, vertexBuffer);

            // get handle to fragment shader's vColor member
            mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");

            // Set color for drawing the triangle
            GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color, 0);

            // get handle to shape's transformation matrix
            mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
            MyGLRenderer.checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation");

            // Apply the projection and view transformation
            GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);
            MyGLRenderer.checkGlError("glUniformMatrix4fv");

            // Draw the square
            GLES20.glDrawElements(
                    GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, drawOrder.length,
                    GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, drawListBuffer);

            // Disable vertex array
            GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
        }

    }
```

I have one more question: Should I create matrix for rotation, scaling and tranformation or I should use `Matrix.multiplyMM(scratch, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0);`
functions as it is.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a question about lighting a square you should add what have you tried and what went wrong or what part are you unclear of. There seem to be no code relevant to lighting in what you posted. There are a lot of posts on how to do that on the web.

To set different colors to the vertices you need a new attribute in your shaders instead of the uniform. The fragment shader should have `attribute vec4 aColor;` and `varying vec4 vColor;` then set `vColor = aColor;` in main. The fragment shader should also contain `varying vec4 vColor;` which replaces `uniform vec4 vColor;`. In the code you need to do all the same as for the positions but use the color array and bind it to `aColor`.

To create matrix for rotation, scaling and translation depends on what you are doing but generally no, it is a bad idea. If you need a reference to those values it is better to keep the angle, scale and translation data as floats and vectors which you use to construct the matrix when needed.